# Create a copy of a table with data without logging

Tags: database, db2

Is there an easy way to copy the data of a table to the same database with different table name without logging.

CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.NEW_TB LIKE SCHEMA.OLD_TB;
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.NEW_TB (SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.OLD_TB);

The above 2 statements will work but the table contains huge amount of data. So is it possible to copy the data without logging?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following with auto commit switched off in your session:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.NEW_TB LIKE SCHEMA.OLD_TB; 
COMMIT;

ALTER TABLE SCHEMA.NEW_TB ACTIVATE NOT LOGGED INITIALLY;
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.NEW_TB 
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.OLD_TB;
COMMIT;
```

It’s important to use `ALTER TABLE` and `INSERT` in the same transaction.